# When writing a function to find an Element in an array, why does this function work, but the other returns -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

When the if statement is not blocked it works and when it is blocked it does not work as intended. Why does this happen? In "findElement2" it's only when I add the "else" statement, that it no longer returns "30" in this case. It returns -1.

```js
let arr = [10, 50, 30, 40, 20];
let n = arr.length;
let key = 30;



 function findElement(arr,n,key)
    {
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (arr[i] == key)
                return arr[i];

        return -1;
    }

function findElement2(arr, n, key){
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (arr[i] == key) {
      return arr[i];
    }else{
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findElement(arr, n, key));
console.log(findElement2(arr, n, key));
```

Comment: findElement2 only works when looking for the 1st element in the array since it returns on the first miss.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `if/else` statement is within a `for loop` & enclosed in `{}` brackets, it runs until the end and the function can only return a single value.

The first function doesn't use the {} brackets, but to do that, they need to be on same line, in this case it is returning first result.

If you add the {} brackets to first function or order it right, you'll see the same result of `-1`

JS may be confused, I know I am! Try changing the parameter names within your function declarations and the associated locals within. While using the same name for the top variables, it may be using the globals instead.

```
function f(a,n) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === n) {
            return `${a[i]}`
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

**After that, you pass your original global variables to it, as you please**.
`f(arr,key)`